# How to pass an option value of Parent job as the "job name" of child job?

Tags: rundeck

I have a main job "Parent" and 2 child jobs "Child_1" & "Child_2" defined in "Project-A".

The Parent job has 1 option name:
"childname" with Allowed Values "Child_1,Child_2"
Only one value can be selected from the drop down.

Within Parent, there is a Job Reference step where I'm trying to pass ${option.childname} in the "Job Name" field to call the selected child job.

However, it is resulting in an error:

```
Job [${option.childname}] not found, project: Project-A
```

How do I get the Parent to run the child job in this manner?
If not, what is the alternate way to select the child job?

My ultimate goal is:

1) Define several jobs within the project.

2) Define one main control job thru which I can select some combination of hostname, application component, environment name, etc. and execute the correct child job. The point is to not have to sift through several jobs (or groups of jobs) to run a particular child job.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A good option to do this is using API or RD CLI wrapped on a shell script passing the option on bash variable.

API Reference:

https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/

A very good Rundeck API examples:

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/95797/rundeck/7TNfX9k#intro

RD CLI:

https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/

Comment: Hi ReinerRDECK, thanks for your response. Would you mind elaborating a bit more?